# How to use docker logs

Tags: docker

The question may be a bit of newbie.
I run `docker exec -it mycontainer bash` to enter into a daemon container(postgresSQL ),
and `echo` something.
now I exit it , and use `docker logs mycontainer` so as to see my echos.

According to

> The docker logs command batch-retrieves logs present at the time of execution.
>   The docker logs --follow command will continue streaming the new output from the container's STDOUT and STDERR.

The `docker logs` listen `STDOUT` of the container, why I don't see my string just *echoed* inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *assume* logging only occurs for the main process in a container. As exec creates a new process, it won't get logged.

Note that `docker logs` works for processes given in the run command e.g:

```
$ ID=$(docker run -d debian sh -c "while true; do echo "hello"; sleep 1; done;")
$ docker logs $ID
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 4):

Docker engine only stores stdout from process with ID 0 (i.e. the process launched by the CMD directive of your Dockerfile).

By the way, on your Docker host, you can inspect the content of container's logs by viewing the file `/var/lib/docker/containers/<ID of your container>/<ID of your container>-json.log`.

This file stores logs in JSON format.